# enable extension in a way other than from typo3 backend

Tags: typo3

I had disabled an extension from Extension manager.but that lead to an error so i cant enable it from typo3 back end. Please help me to  recover again to the same state as before

Comment: Which error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a state where an extension breaks basic backend functionality try using the Install Tool. In the part „important actions“ is an action check for broken extensions and probably an action clear opcache. Do both (start with opcache if available) as this should fix about 90% of all such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try [TYPO3-Console](https://github.com/TYPO3-Console/TYPO3-Console) command [extension:activate](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/typo3_console/CommandReference/Index.html#extension-activate)

You can use

```
./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:list
```

to see all extensions, and

```
./vendor/bin/typo3cms extension:activate extension-key
```

to activate that extension